# Как в строке найти слово с большой буквы?

Tags: php, строки

Как с помощью PHP в строке найти слово с большой буквы, не считая первого слова в строке, и это слово с большой буквы занести в переменную ?

Comment: Главное тут определить, какие символы кроме первого входят в слово (например, `-` может? (a `+`?))

Comment: @So-so слово может быть только одно в строке? Или надо учитывать все возможные совпадения?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Например так:

```
$input = 'Foo bar Baz';
$word_found = (bool)preg_match('/(?!^)(?P<word>[A-ZА-ЯЁ]\S*)/', $input, $matches);
if ($word_found) {
    echo($matches['word']);
} else {
    echo('None');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Тем, кто не хочет использовать регулярки можно так:

```
$string = "One two Free Six";
$explode = explode(" ", $string);
$first = strlen($explode[0]) + 1;
array_shift($explode);

echo $first + strcspn(implode(" ", $explode), "ABCDEFGHJIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ");
```

Comment: Тем, кто не хочет использовать регулярки ... Мне было проще прочитать шаблон '/(?!^)(?P[A-ZА-ЯЁ]\S*)/', чем ваш алгоритм ;-)